# Утилиты для диагностики HDD

Tags: hdd, поиск-программ

Интересуют утилиты проверенные временем, **бесплатные**, желательно портабл для просмотра релокатед секторов, состояния диска, необходим для принятия решения менять винт или он рабочий!  Благодарю заранее, многим будет интересно!

Comment: Portable не получится, вероятно, поскольку нужны админские права для большинства действий.

Answer (score 2):

smartctl решает! Ось то какая?

Comment: win7 ******************

Comment: [тут](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki) виндовый порт без GUI

Answer (score 1):

Список утилит для работы с дисками, статистика, диагностика ... :

[image: HDD утилиты диагностика статистика]

1. **WinContig** - дефрагментатор HDD и Flash. Умеет выборочно дефрагментировать файлы и папки.
2. **PageDfrg** - дефрагментация реестра и файла подкачки при загрузке 32-разрядного Windows
3. **Ghost** - создание/клонирование образов дисков/разделов
4. **Ghost Explorer** - просмотр и редактирование образов созданных программой Ghost
5. **HDD Low Level Format Tool** - низкоуровневое форматирование
6. **MiniTool Partition Wizard** - работа с разделами HDD и Flash, разбиение, форматирование, изменение размера
7. **Check Flash** - тест работоспособности и скорости. Редактирование, сохранение и восстановление раздела/диска/загрузчика
8. **ChkDskGui** - интерфейс для консольной утилиты Chkdsk
9. **UNetbootin** - загрузка ISO-образов CD/DVD дисков с Linux/BSD и создание из них Live USB
10. **Rufus** - форматирование и создание загрузочных Flash
    DirectGRUB - GUI для создания загрузочной флешки с подгрузкой ISO
11. **USBMaster** - управление USB-устройствами хранения информации
12. **NonStopCopy** - копирование с поврежденных носителей
13. **R-Studio** - восстановление удалённых файлов и повреждённых разделов с HDD, CD, Flash и RAID
14. **UFS Explorer** - просмотр файловых систем (можно повреждённых) в том числе Linux и MacOS и восстановление данных
15. **DM Disk Editor and Data Recovery** - поиск, редактирование и восстановление информации на дисках
16. **Back2Life** - надежное, удобное и быстрое восстановление удаленных данных
17. **HDHacker** - сохранение и восстановление MBR физ. дисков, BootSector лог. дисков или specified sector любых дисков
18. **BOOTICE** - манипуляция загрузочными секторами с широкими возможностями. Загрузка различных ОС, восстановление загрузки
19. **MultiBoot** - восстановление загрузчика Windows Vista/7 и создании мультизагрузочного меню
20. **EasyBCD** - менеджер загрузки операционных систем, создание мультизагрузки
21. **Victoria** - тест, анализ и лечение HDD
22. **HD Tune Pro** - показания S.M.A.R.T. Диагностика и тест HDD, SSD, RAID, Flash. Управление питанием и акустическим режимом
23. **CrystalDiskInfo** - показания S.M.A.R.T. Управление питанием и акустическим режимом
24. **HDD Scanner** - показывает распределение информации на диске/папке
25. **HDI** - индикатор чтения/записи жесткого диска

Comment: Пожалуйста, перепишите картинку текстом! Поисковые системы не смогут проиндексировать ваш ответ-изображение.

Comment: @Arhad переписал.